# How to create a class with its data and get method in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new C# developer and I am trying to develop a simple ASP.NET application. I am struggling now with creating a class with its static data and get method. I have static data that will never be changed and I would like to put them in a class that includes, Properties, Constructors, GetData() method and  its data. So how can I do that?

I've tried writing the class but I am still facing difficulty with the GetData() method and with populating it with the data.

Here's my C# code:

```
public class TestItem
    {
        //Properties
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }


        // Default Constructor
        public TestItem() { }


        // Constructor
        public TestItem(int id, int parentId, string title, string description, string url)
        {
            Id = id;
            ParentId = parentId;
            Title = title;
            Description = description;
            Url = url;
        }


        // Get Method
        public IEnumerable<TestItem> GetTestItemItems()
        {
            List<TestItem> testItems = new List<TestItem>();
            try
            {
                testItems = (from item in TestItem
                             select item);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return testItems;
        }


    // Populate the Data
        List<TestItem> items = new List<TestItem>
        {
            new TestItem
            {
                Id = 0,
                ParentId = 0,
                Title = "",
                Description = "",
                Url = ""
            },
        };


    }
```

My problem now is with the GetData() method as I am getting a red line within the try block and I don't know why. **Could anyone help me in this matter?**

```
// Get Method
    public IEnumerable<TestItem> GetTestItemItems()
    {
        List<TestItem> testItems = new List<TestItem>();
        try
        {
            testItems = (from item in TestItem
                         select item);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return testItems;
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @II ARROWS for his try to help me here. I tried his answer, however, I am still getting an error which is the following:

[image]

Please note, I changed the names from TestItem to SystemMenu and TestItemRepository  to SystemMenuRepository. My ultimate goal of this class is to use it later in another page where I can get its static data as a DataTable. **How can I do that?**

Comment: Your select-statement looks strange anyway. Yoy have to have a list from which to select any items, not simply the classname. However you may use `testItems = myCollection.ToList()` then.

Comment: OT but change `throw ex` to just `throw`.  By explicitly rethrowing an exception you truncate the stack trace.  That said, what use is an exception handler that does nothing but rethrow the exception?  That's the same as no exception handler at all.  You should never arbitrarily catch exceptions.  ONLY catch specific exceptions that can reasonably be thrown and that you intend to do something specific about.

Comment: From the get method, i am wondering what are you trying to get. There are no input lists and the list that you have applied a Linq would still be empty as per the first statement of that method. Can you please recheck you logic. Also remove the statement inside the Try block.

Comment: There is absolutely no point in empty `throw;` block as the program will do this anyway. Not speaking of `throw ex;` that does even worse as @jmcilhinney noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your code, you claim that you need a static "data" but I don't see any (your sample code has a public constructor) and the GetData method is not static (besides the error already pointed to you of getting a class instead of your list).

To declare a static method, you should use the static keyword after the public keyword, but you will need also static data (or making it on the fly), since you cannot rely on instances of the class.

You should probabily use the singleton pattern, here some reference for you:

What is it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

How to implement it: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

In short, a singleton is class that cannot be instantiated from the outside world, calling a static method (your GetData) it istantiates itself the first time it's called keeping track of the instance using a private static field.
Then, returns the data.

Here you have two classes, one with your elements and one with the list of those elements (this is a simple implementation, refer to the link above):

```
public class TestItem
{
    //Properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    // Constructor
    public TestItem(int id, int parentId, string title, string description, string url)
    {
        Id = id;
        ParentId = parentId;
        Title = title;
        Description = description;
        Url = url;
    }
}



public class TestItemsRepository
{
    private List<TestItem> data;
    private static TestItemsRepository instance;

    private TestItemsRepository()
    {
        //Populate data
        data = new List<TestItem>
        {
            new TestItem
            {
                Id = 0,
                ParentId = 0,
                Title = "",
                Description = "",
                Url = ""
            },
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TestItem> GetTestItems()
    {
        if (instance==null)
        {
             instance = new TestItemsRepository();
        }
        return instance.data;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but in your repository class, I am getting a red line under `instance`. Could you please explain to me why?

Comment: Because I did not tested it... lol
Changed the name of the field "singleton" to "instance" as I referenced it in the GetTestItems method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying help me and sorry for bothering you with my questions. I still don't get it right. I will update my question in a few minutes so you can see my trials.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could check my updated question now and see if you could help me in this regard.

Comment: I made a really bad mistake, I forgot to mark the "instance" field as static, as it's needed too because it is being referenced by a static method.
Anyway, I suggest you to read the article before moving on. If you had read it, you could have understand and correct my simple mistake.

Comment: it works well with me now. I went through the article but it is a bit advanced for me. One more question if you don't mind, how can I get the data now in another page?

Comment: Asking this here is not the way to use SO, anyway you just need to call TestItemRepository.GetTestItems() from every page you need (just put the classes in the app_code folder).

Answer (score 0):

If your data should be static, you should declare your items  as static and also method GetTestItemItems as static.

In method GetTestItemItems you should just return items  list, I don't see the point of returning new list.

Answer (score 0):

As for why you get the error here:

```
testItems = (from item in TestItem
             select item);
```

`TestItem` is a type, not a list, so how can you enumerate over it?  That should be:

```
testItems = (from item in items
             select item);
```

That's not necessarily great code still but it addresses your first immediate issue.  You then need to worry about types.  As your method is declared as type `IEnumerable<TestItem>`, you can declare `testItems` as that type too.  Alternatively, call `ToList` on your LINQ query in order to create a `List<TestItem>` that you can assign to the variable as is.  The better option depends whether you're happy for your method to return an unrealised LINQ query.

Of course, why would you do any of that when you could just add a read-only property that returns `items` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

The red line comes as you try to assign an instance of `IEnumerable<T>` to a List of type `TestItem`. However `TestItem` is a class, not any enumerable collection whereas you cannot iterate over it using `select from`.

So you have to change the source of your select from `TestItem` to `items` which actually holds your data.

After this you can simplify your code as follows:

```
var testItems = items.ToList()
```

Ommitting all this messy linq-statements. However your `items`-variable holds only one single item with the `id = 0`. You have to pull some data into that list first by calling `items.Add(...)` before you can do anything with it.

Furthermore you can also delete the try-catch as all you do is simply rethrow any exception which would have been thrown anyway.